# What is the right approach to use for factoring a rational inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is an example:

$\frac{x^2 - 3x + 2}{x + 1} -5 > 0$

My approach would be to factor, find the undefined areas and the zeros, and then pick some points in the intervals left to see what I find. I'm not really sure if that's the right way to go, and to find the zeros I would just throw an equals sign in instead of the inequality and find the roots. Is this the right approach, and are there any techniques to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a general approach, but in this example $x=-1$ is 'special', so split the consideration into $I_- = (-\infty,-1)$ and $I_+ = (-1, +\infty)$.

On $I_+$, we have $x^2 - 3x + 2 - 5 (x + 1) = x^2-8x-3 > 0$. The factors are $4 \pm \sqrt{19}$, hence if $x \in I_+$, then $\frac{x^2 - 3x + 2}{x + 1} -5 > 0$ iff $x > 4 + \sqrt{19}$ or $x < 4 - \sqrt{19}$.

On $I_-$, we have $x^2 - 3x + 2 - 5 (x + 1) =x^2-8x-3 < 0$. From the previous reasoning, we have that if $x \in I_-$, then $\frac{x^2 - 3x + 2}{x + 1} -5 \leq 0$.

Hence $\frac{x^2 - 3x + 2}{x + 1} -5 > 0$ iff $ x \in (-1,4 - \sqrt{19}) \cup (4 + \sqrt{19}, +\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

I would take the $5$ up into the rational function.

$$\frac{x^2-3x+2-5(x+1)}{x+1}>0$$
$$\frac{x^2-8x-3}{x+1}>0$$

Solving the quadratic on top gives

$x=4\pm\sqrt{19}$

So we have

$$\frac{(x-4-\sqrt{19})(x-4+\sqrt{19})}{x+1}>0$$

Now we have $3$ places where it can change sign: $-1$ and $4\pm \sqrt{19}$. For very large positive values this will clearly be positive, and it will flip signs (as each factor flips sign individually) as we move right to left along $\mathbb{R}$. This implies that it's positive on $(4+\sqrt{19},\infty)\cup (-1,4-\sqrt{19})$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work, but the $-5$ makes some trouble.  Factoring makes it easy to compare with $0$, but not so much with other numbers.  My first try would be to incorporate the $5$ in the fraction, getting $$\frac {x^2-8x-3}{x+1} \gt 0$$  Unfortunately, the numerator doesn't factor easily, but I would just use the quadratic formula:  $$\frac{(x-4-\sqrt{19})(x-4+\sqrt{19)}}{x+1}\gt 0$$ and the two roots and one asymptote are visible.